# Oscommerce language install problem

Tags: oscommerce

I am new to oscommerce. I am trying to install some language pack(german, french). I finished installing successfully but when I change the language from front-end, I get this warning:

**Warning: oscTemplate::include(includes/languages/french/modules/boxes/bm_categories.php) [osctemplate.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\osc\includes\classes\osc_template.php on line 86**

Actually many warning like this. I could not find action_recorder, boxes, header_tags, social_bookmarks in the module folder of these language Which I found in english language. I think these missing folders are creating problem. How can I solve this problem? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if the language pack you have installed is incomplete, the way to correct this error is to record each warning, locate the language file for that module and place it into the proper language folder.

A tip to finding the language file would be to look in the english language folder (includes/languages/**english**/) for the correct files (bm_categories.php), translate them to the necessary language, and then place them into the proper language folder.

Example:
1.   Download this file 
includes/languages/**english**/modules/boxes/bm_categories.php

1. Translate into french
2. Upload to the server into this folder
   includes/languages/**french**/modules/boxes/